# Angular Material - is there any expandable menu feature in the current build?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm working on a prototype and wondering if there's any existing feature I can use to setup an expandable menu, or will I have to build my own directive to make that functionality work at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an mdMenu component is currently planned for version 0.10 - they are currently working on 0.9. See this issue: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/78

Collapsible sidebar menu also coming in 0.10: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/985

Comment: I was thinking more the expand/collapse in a sidebar, that expands a parent header to show a hidden menu with child links. Just like they use in the sidebar on http://material.angularjs.org (ie. Demos, Theming, Layout...). Looks like they used a custom directive to build those.

Comment: I think I saw something about that recently too. Let me see if I can find it.

Comment: @ngDeveloper - see my edit. Is that more what you were looking for?